# Adapter data changes alternatively

Tags: android

the situation is that the Adapter result keeps changing alternatively
i.e

First it is: 
[http://cache3.asset-cache.net/xt/540053243.jpg?v=1&g=fs1|0|FPG|53|243&s=1&b=RjI4, 
then:
[http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xt/471950448.jpg?v=1&g=fs1|0|EPL|50|448&s=1&b=RjI4

for the same network call.

This is my Adapter class:

```
public ImageCustomAdapter(ArrayList<ModelGettyImages> images,Context context) {
    this.images = images;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, parent, false);
    ImagesViewHolder imagesViewHolder = new ImagesViewHolder(view);


    return imagesViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImagesViewHolder holder, int position) {


    List<String> text = images.get(position).getTitle();
    Log.d("TitleAdapter : ",images.get(position).getTitle().toString());
    List<String> image = images.get(position).getImagePath();
    Log.d("ImageAdapter : ", images.get(position).getImagePath().toString());
    holder.title.setText(text.get(position));
    Picasso.with(context).load(image.get(position)).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    public ImagesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

         image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
         title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

Interesting thing is that Title field is the same.

Response class:

```
 private ModelGettyImages getImageDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {

    boolean ascending = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Ascending",false);
    Log.d("Ascending",Boolean.toString(ascending));
    boolean descending = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Descending",false);
    Log.d("descending",Boolean.toString(descending));

    String pathURI = "";
    JSONObject imageData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    int resultCount = imageData.optInt("result_count");
    Log.d("Result Count: ", Integer.toString(resultCount));

    JSONArray imageArray = imageData.optJSONArray("images");
    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject img = imageArray.optJSONObject(i);
        allID.add(i,img.optString("id"));
        allTitles.add(i,img.optString("title"));
        Log.d("Image ID: ", allID.get(i));
        Log.d("Image Title: ", allTitles.get(i));
        JSONArray imagePath = img.optJSONArray("display_sizes");
        for (int j = 0; j < imagePath.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject jb = imagePath.optJSONObject(j);
            allImagePath.add(j,jb.getString("uri"));
            Log.d("Image Path: ", allImagePath.get(j));

        }

        if( ascending )
        {
            Log.d("Ass","True");

            Collections.sort(allTitles, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                    return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                }
            });
        }
        else if( descending )
        {
            Log.d("Des","True");

            Collections.sort(allTitles, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                    return s2.compareToIgnoreCase(s1);
                }
            });
        }


        Log.d("Image Title Sort: ", allTitles.get(i));

        modelGettyImages.setID(allID);
        modelGettyImages.setTitle(allTitles);
        modelGettyImages.setImagePath(allImagePath);
        ImagesList.add(modelGettyImages);




    }


    return modelGettyImages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset imageview before loading url in it use this code

```
Picasso.with(this.context).cancelRequest(holder.image);
```

before

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image.get(position)).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image);
```

Comment: no the problem is not with Picasso, but     List<String> image = images.get(position).getImagePath(); keeps changing

Comment: the results for images are reversed, i.e last image comes as first in my list

Comment: can you post your json?

Comment: First Json Element in my Response class: http://cache3.asset-cache.net/xt/540053243.jpg?v=1&g=fs1|0|FPG|53|243&s=1&b=RjI4

Comment: First Element in my Adapter Class: [http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xt/471950448.jpg?v=1&g=fs1|0|EPL|50|448&s=1&b=RjI4

Comment: you have list of paths for one image is that right? that's why you used     List<String> image = images.get(position).getImagePath(); you got this object of list from which you need to get image path you are again passing position to list object to get path for picasso

Comment: Sorry i did not get you.

Comment: if you post your json i will explain you better

Comment: Hey, but the first item in my Adapter is not the same which i get in the response

Comment: List<String> image = images.get(position).getImagePath();
is returning the wrong item

Comment: is your sorting working properly ? Debug it and let me knw

Comment: Sorting works correctly, one thing to note is that "Title field" is in sync with my response but not the "Image field" although same instructions are used for both

Comment: Works Correct:         List<String> text = images.get(position).getTitle();

Comment: Hey i found my problem

Comment: The response which i'm send is reversed

Comment: The problem is with my parsing of the JSON, somehow it seems that i'm not sending the response for the ImagePath in order, but the Title field is in order. Doubt what is happening in my Inner ForLoop.